# Sqlite3 installed but says it's not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, macports

I'm going through a tutorial to install Rails. When I first try to use MacPorts to upgrade sqlite3 using 'sudo port upgrade sqlite3' the response I get is 'sqlite3 is not installed'; however when I ask 'which sqlite3' I am given the path where it is '/usr/bin/sqlite3', I tried running 'sudo port upgrade sqlite3' in that path as well, but no luck.

Is it installed or not? How should I proceed with the upgrade/installation of sqlite and Rails? Thanks

Comment: Did you install sqlite3 via ports? If not, it probably won't know what to do with it.

Comment: No, you are right, I didn't, but it already has sqlite3 apparently

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
which sqlite3
```

answered '/usr/bin/sqlite3', I would say that sqlite3 is installed on your system.
You can also try

```
sqlite3
```

which should answer (version can differ)

```
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Exit with:

```
.quit
```

I would go ahead and try to install the gem:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

If it doesn't complain you are good to go, otherwise post the error message.

As an additional piece of advice, I've had some bad experiences with MacPorts, try [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) instead.

hth

Comment: The error message I am getting is: "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory."

Comment: This comes when you need to be admin to install gems. Try 'sudo gem install sqlite3'

Comment: I tried again nor after installing ruby with rvm and it worked, thanks